# how to set a unique constraint in a foreign key relationship?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL so please forgive meif this is a very rookie question.
I want to set a unique constraint in foreign key relationship.

say for instance I have a table called `Author` and a table called `Article` and `Article` is related to author with a foreign key relationship (one Author corresponding to several articles). I want a constraint such that, for particular author there can't be two articles with the same name. (if two articles are of the same name then they can't be of the same author). 
How would I achieve this in SQL while creating the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a unique constraint in `Article`:

```
alter table articles add constraint unq_articlename_author
    unique (article_name, author);
```

This assumes that "author name" is equivalent to the foreign key used to define the relationship.

Comment: I would rephrase `unique (article_name, author_id)` for clarity.